# swift access modifiers correct usage

Tags: swift

Suppose I have the following struct inside a `StorageService` framework :

```
struct Post {
    public let author: String
    public let description: String
    public let image: String
    public let likes: Int
    public let views: Int
}
```

So to access its fields from another module I mark all fields with `public` keyword - it's clear. But should I mark the name `Post` itself to be public :

`public struct Post` ...

I tried both ways but I see no differences (with `public struct Post` and `struct Post`).

What is the right way to follow here?

Comment: You need public if Post is declared in a library and need to be accessed from outside that library.

Answer (score 0):

The access modifier of the type itself will control the accessibility of the type and hence making any properties more accessible than the type itself is useless, since you cannot access properties of a type that you don't know about.

In order to be able to use the `Post` type from outside your framework, you need to declare `Post` as `public`.

This makes the type itself and all of its properties accessible from outside your framework:

```
public struct Post {
    public let author: String
    public let description: String
    public let image: String
    public let likes: Int
    public let views: Int
}
```

On the other hand, if you don't want to expose some specific properties/methods publicly, you can always use an accessibility modifier that is stricter than the type's modifier.

```
public struct Post {
    public let author: String
    public let image: String
    public let likes: Int
    let description: String // can only be accessed from inside the module
    private let views: Int // can only be accessed from the Post type itself
}
```